# Understanding Wasserstein metric

Tags: probability, measure-theory, metric-spaces

According to Wikipedia, the Wasserstein metric between two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ is defined as follows,

$$W_p(\mu,\nu)=\left(\inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma(\mu,\nu)} \int_{M*M}d(x,y)^p d \gamma(x,y) \right)^{1/p}$$
where $\Gamma(\mu,\nu)$ is the collection of all measures on $M*M$ with marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$.

From my understanding, $\Gamma(\mu,\nu)$ only contains one possible joint probability measure for $\mu$ and $\nu$. Does any other probability measure exist?

Comment: Why do you think there is only one such measure? There is at least one (the product measure), but there are many more.  Think about $2\times2$ contingency tables. There are many tables with the same marginals.

Answer (score 1):

In the genreal case,  $\ \Gamma(\mu,\nu)$ doesn't have to contain only one probability mesaure. As @Hans Engler commented, If you take, for example,  $X=\{1,2\}$ and $\mu=\nu=\{1,1\}$ two measures on $X$, then $\mu\times\nu$ is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0.5 & 0.5\\0.5 & 0.5\end{pmatrix}$ which belong to $\ \Gamma(\mu,\nu)$ 
 But any 2x2 doubly  [stochastic  matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) (in particular, any [permutaion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)) is also an element of $\ \Gamma(\mu,\nu)$.